# Set button tag for different sections of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I list of contacts from Web Service and display it in contacts 'sectioned' tableView as seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Issue is I get same tag values for checkboxes of first row for section A as well as section S. I have sorted one array and displayed in the indexed table view. How to get different tag values depending on indexPath.row irrespective of number of sections displayed. Here's what I tried

```
    In cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
     UIButton *checkBox;
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            checkBox = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 8, 30, 30)];
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 13, 30, 30)];
        }

        //int cnt = 0;
        // for (int i = indexPath.section - 1; i > 0 ; i--)
        // {
        //     cnt += [[objectsForCharacters objectForKey:[arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:i]] count]; //arrayOfCharachters has char 'A' to 'Z'
        // }

        //checkBox.tag = cnt + indexPath.row;

        [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [checkBox setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];
        return cell;
    }

    -(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender
    {

        CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableViewContact];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewContact indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
        UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
        NSLog(@"Tag number = %d", [sender tag]);

        if([tappedButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"]])
        {
            [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checkBoxMarked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            if(indexPath != Nil)
            {
                NSString *finalIntId = [mutableArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // store check box ids in mutableArrayOfIds
                NSLog(@"Tagged checked button id = %@", finalIntId);
                [arrayOfIds addObject:finalIntId];
            }
            //NSString *finalIntId = [mutableArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:tappedButton.tag];
            //NSString *finalIntId = [mutableArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else
        {
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"UnChecked");
            //[arrayOfIds removeObjectAtIndex:tappedButton.tag];

        }
    }

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ([arrayOfCharacters count] == 0)
    {
        return @"";
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:section]];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     NSArray *toBeReturned = [NSArray arrayWithArray:
                                 [@"A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|#"
                                  componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];

      return toBeReturned;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{


        NSInteger count = 0;

        for (NSString *character in arrayOfCharacters) {

            if ([character isEqualToString:title]) {
                return count;
            }

            count ++;
        }

        return 0;


}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

        return [arrayOfCharacters count];
        //return 1;

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


        //return [mutableArray count];
        return [[objectsForCharacters objectForKey:[arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:section]] count];

}
```

Comment: better subclass the tableview cell , there by u can get whole info of the cell including sections and rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code which solved my issue

```
NSInteger rowNumber = 0;
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section ; i++)
    {
        rowNumber += [self tableView:self.tableViewContact numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    }

    rowNumber += indexPath.row;

[checkBox setTag:rowNumber]; //checkBox is UIButton in cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

Answer (score 21):

you are setting the same tag value for all sections which have same row.
The indexPath has two properties, {section,row}.

Lets say section A has two rows,

```
for row1 -> indexPath.section=0, indexPath.row=0;
for row2->  indexPath.section=0, indexPath.row=1;
```

Lets say section S has two rows,

```
for row1 -> indexPath.section=1, indexPath.row=0;
for row2->  indexPath.section=1, indexPath.row=1;
```

So, for row1 of section A and row1 of section S, you are setting the same tag value which is 0.There is your problem.

Try setting tag value like below.

```
button.tag = indexPath.section*1000 +indexPath.row;
```

when retrieving the section and row,

```
NSInteger section = (button.tag)/1000;
NSInteger row = (button.tag)%1000;
```

Comment: so with reference to last two lines, how do I use section and row to store the tag value in array?

Comment: why do you need to store the tagValue in array.because you dont need to store it ,as it can be known by sender.tag.

Comment: If you explicitly need to store it, create an array as global (NSMutableArray *mutableArray). And add as [mutableArray addObject:sender.tag].But before adding check whether its already added  by using for loop and check tag value matching.

Comment: If you observe there are check boxes on the left of each tableView cell.. If I check it, it will store that tag value in the array..

Comment: ok ok gotcha. you cant store NSIntegers in an arrray, you should convert it to an NSNumber which is an objective c object. use [NSNumber numberWithInt:button.tag]; hope this helps.And to later get the integer from this number ,use number.integerValue

Comment: so how do I merge section and row eg. [NSNumber numberWithInt:(section + row)button.tag]; instead of  [NSNumber numberWithInt:button.tag];

Comment: when you set button's tag, you set it as shown in the answer. button.tag = indexPath.section*1000 +indexPath.row; Now your button tag has both section and row stored in it. so adding it to the array [NSNumber numberWithInt:button.tag]; would work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45613/discussion-between-optimus-prime-and-santhu)

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this...



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    UIButton *checkBox =[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280, 10, 50, 44)];
    checkBox.backgroundColor =[UIColor orangeColor];
    [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:event:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [checkBox setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];

    return cell;
}
- (void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tv]; //here tv is TableView Object
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tv indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

    NSLog(@"value of indePath.section %d ,indexPath.row %d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);

}
```

Comment: how do i store the tag value inside the array depending on indexpath.section and indexpath.row.   Eg. [array addObject:[arrayOfIds objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section + indexPath.row)]];

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are assigning tag to buttons INDEPENDENT of sections.
Both of First Row of Sections A & S have row = 0. so Tag Assigned to their respective button is 0. You should assign them Keeping reference to your sections.
i would suggest to assign accessibility hint with comma separated form containing Section,Row.

And in your method
`-(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender
    {
      //pick string from comma separated form. 1st is your section, 2nd is row.
    }`

second option is Do what ever your doing and implement your Button method like this.

```
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
     ... indexpath.section is your section , index path.row is your row.
    }
```

There is Third option as well.

in `cellforRowAtIndexpath` assign your Button a title 
`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
[btn setTitle:<#Your Row#> forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[btn setTag<#Your Section#>];`

so upon Receiving in your Button Method you can have both Section (Tag) and Row (Title for Disabled state).

```
-(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender { [button titleForState:UIControlStateDisabled]; // your Row
```

button.tag //your Section }

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Each section you may know the count of section right, then add count of individual row.

```
 [[fieldTitlesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section - 1] count] + indexPath.row
```

Where fieldTitlesList is the array of your sections.